# How to export NFS shares rw to Windows

Tags: rhel, samba, nfs

I have an application server running on RHEL6. Files from RHEL6 are being shared via NFS (`/etc/exports` --> `/data` *(rw,sync)) to workstations with Windows. On Windows txt files are accessible as read-only. Users are asking me all the time to remove ro attribute.
How can I solve this issue from RHEL site?
I tried to use `chmod 777 *` on all files but it didn't help. 
Do you think that Samba might be helpful to share the files?

Comment: If you're sharing with Windows my experience has been that samba is the way to go.  I don't have any insight about why the NFS shares are seeming to be read only, but I've had a bad time in the past trying to get windows and linux permissions to play nicely together

Comment: I didnt understand why did you want rwx on text files?Users can change contains of the text files when you set to rwx.Did Application server create all text files with ro ?Maybe Application server can change all text files to rw?

Comment: I did rwx to grant all possible rights to files to make sure that rhel attributes will not impact in my problems.

Comment: Unfortunately vendor of the application is not very flexible so this will be my last chance

Comment: You have seen this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771698%28v=ws.11%29.aspx, yes? Or this http://superuser.com/q/525473/311391?

Comment: What I knew when you shared NFS to Windows.Windows needed Unix services pack from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

SAMBA is the answer. No problems with attributes. Thx